# WIS 10901 error while refreshing Webi report

Tags: business-objects, webi

While refreshing Webi report I am getting an error:

> A database error occured. The database error text is: (CS) "Unexpected behavior" . (WIS 10901)

All the objects are parsing in the universe and Server is also responding. What can be the possible reason?

We are also able to run query in the database using database client tool.

Answer (score 0):

If the error message appears after the a long time it might just be a timeout issue.

Else, you could try to import a version of the report that works in CMS to your local drive, rename it and run again.

Answer (score 0):

It can be caused by some special character in the data combined with the fact that the server language settings do not foresee such character and therefore Business Objects cannot parse it for presentation.
If that is the case you might need to configure an environment variable of the server (like NLS_LANG) setting it to a value such that those special characters in your data can be handled by Business Objects.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, the error appera when some objet from the data base has changed or does not exists anymore. So we need to delete this object in the Universe or be sure that the field exists in the data base with the same name and type.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with my reports. After couple hour of "investigation", I found.
I create Object in my universe, and set inappropriate type of object data Number, when value in database have type Character.

It throw me oracle Error (ORA-01722), and Bussiness Object error (WIS 10901), though SQL copied from report creator interface, executed directly on database return proper data.